# Minecraft datapack with a void dimension?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'd like to outsource sone of my more client-heavy machinery in 1.14.4 Java Edition to a custom void dimension. I haven't reached the End yet, which might be one alternative solution to this issue.

What I'm thinking about is a custom portal which leads to a dimension with only a bedrock and a portal back to the overworld. The purpose of this dimension would be performing render-heavy automated tasks.

Is it possible to make a custom dimension using only datapacks?

I've found an example here (Portal at 3:30):

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Fabian already said, commands can not add another dimension.

The datapack featured in the video uses the upper half of the nether. It even uses parts of the nether for terrain generation:
It clones netherrack and nether quartz ore from parts of the nether and replaces those with other blocks (different for each layer, in some layers the air gets filled, too).

Answer (score 2):

## No.

Commands cannot add dimensions.